# Hazelcast Jcloud discovery is not working for Azure

Tags: hazelcast

I was trying to use hazelcast-jclouds.3.7.2 discovery mechanism for Azure.However, couldn't make it work its giving following execption.

> 1) No implementation for java.lang.String annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=oauth.endpoint) was bound.
>
> at org.jclouds.oauth.v2.config.OAuthModule.oauthEndpoint(OAuthModule.java:63)
>
> 1 error
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
>           ... 33 more
>   Caused by: com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:
>
> 1) No implementation for java.lang.String annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=oauth.endpoint) was bound.
>   at org.jclouds.oauth.v2.config.OAuthModule.oauthEndpoint(OAuthModule.java:63)
>
> 1 error
>           at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:435)
>           at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:154)
>           at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:106)
>           at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
>           at org.jclouds.ContextBuilder.buildInjector(ContextBuilder.java:405)
>           at org.jclouds.ContextBuilder.buildInjector(ContextBuilder.java:328)
>           at org.jclouds.ContextBuilder.buildView(ContextBuilder.java:615)
>           at org.jclouds.ContextBuilder.buildView(ContextBuilder.java:595)
>           at com.hazelcast.jclouds.ComputeServiceBuilder.build(ComputeServiceBuilder.java:207)
>           at com.hazelcast.jclouds.JCloudsDiscoveryStrategy.start(JCloudsDiscoveryStrategy.java:70)
>           at com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.impl.DefaultDiscoveryService.start(DefaultDiscoveryService.java:63)
>           at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.start(Node.java:385)
>           at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:137)
>           at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.constructHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:196)
>           at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:175)
>           at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:125)
>           at com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(Hazelcast.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
>           ... 34 more

Following are the hazelcast-jcloud configurations

```
        JoinConfig joinConfig = getNetworkConfig().getJoin();
        joinConfig.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
        joinConfig.getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled(false);
        getProperties().put("hazelcast.discovery.enabled", "true");
        DiscoveryConfig discoveryConfig = joinConfig.getDiscoveryConfig();

        Map<String, Comparable> properties = new HashMap<String, Comparable>();
        properties.put("provider", "azurecompute-arm");
        properties.put("identity", "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx");//Principal client ID
        properties.put("credential", "xxxxxxxxxxx"); //Principal client secret
        properties.put("endpoint", "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/Subscription   id  ");

        JCloudsDiscoveryStrategyFactory jcloudDiscoveryStrategyFactory = new JCloudsDiscoveryStrategyFactory();
        DiscoveryStrategyConfig discoveryStrategyConfig = new DiscoveryStrategyConfig(jcloudDiscoveryStrategyFactory,
                properties);

        ArrayList<DiscoveryStrategyConfig> discoveryStrategyConfigs = new ArrayList<DiscoveryStrategyConfig>();
        discoveryStrategyConfigs.add(discoveryStrategyConfig);
        discoveryConfig.setDiscoveryStrategyConfigs(discoveryStrategyConfigs);
```

Please suggest if there is a solution/workaround for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`hazelcast-jclouds` module does not support Azure for now. Please track the issue here: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-jclouds/issues/10

Comment: You can use Hazelcast Azure Discovery plug-in as a workaround: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-azure

Comment: Thanks for the response.The workaround provided is already tested and its working.However we need some generic  discovery strategy that should work on all cloud env.